# Aumentar PDF de tamaño y centrarlo

Tags: php, html5, html2pdf

Cordial saludo compañero tengo un problema al mostrar un pdf, en el codigo le doy la opcion de fullpage y sale de un tamaño pequeñoal lado izquierdo, como puedo hacer que sea un poco mas grande y que quede centrado.

este es mi codigo:

```
    # metodo generar reporte
public function generarReporte($numero) {ob_start();
    $gestorCita = new GestorCita();
    $result = $gestorCita->consultarCitaId($numero);
    ob_start();
    require_once 'Vista/html/reporteCita.php';
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    require_once 'Vista/pdf/vendor/autoload.php';
    $html2pdf = new \Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf('P','A4','es');
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode("fullpage");
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
    $html2pdf->Output("Informacion de la Cita.pdf");
}
```

Este es el html:

```html
<?php
$fila = $result->fetch_object();
?>
<h1 style="text-align: center">Informacion Cita</h1>
<table style="border: 1px solid #000; font-size: 12pt; align:center;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="border:1px solid #000; text-align: center">Datos del Paciente</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Documento</td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->pacIdentificacion?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->pacNombres." ".$fila->pacApellidos?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="border:1px solid #000; text-align: center">Datos del Medico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Documento</td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->medIdentificacion?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nombres</td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->medNombres." ".$fila->medApellidos?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="border:1px solid #000; text-align: center">Datos de la cita</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Numero</td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->idCita?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fecha</td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->citFecha?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hora</td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->citHora?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Numero Consultorio</td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->idConsultorio?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre del Consultorio</td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->conNombre?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Estado</td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->citEstado?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Observaciones</td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->citObservaciones?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Esta es la imagen del PDF.

[image: Interfaz del pdf]

Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Debes poner unas CSS al HTML que fuercen a dibujar la tabla ocupando todo el contenedor, tal como harías en pantalla.

Según la documentación (HTML2PDF se basa en TCPDF) SetDisplayMode define la forma de ver el PDF en el visor, no el contenido en la pagina.

> **SetDisplayMode(mixed zoom [, string layout])**
>
> **Description**
>
> Defines the
> way the document is to be displayed by the viewer. The zoom level can
> be set: pages can be displayed entirely on screen, occupy the full
> width of the window, use real size, be scaled by a specific zooming
> factor or use viewer default (configured in the Preferences menu of
> Adobe Reader). The page layout can be specified too: single at once,
> continuous display, two columns or viewer default.

Fuente: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setdisplaymode.htm

Las CSS que se gestionan en HTML2PDF no son siempre iguales que las estándar, tendrás que pelearte un poco si hace cosas extremas, pero los `width` y `text-align` funcionan igual que en el navegador.

Mirate algún ejemplo, porque realmente es potente:

https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/examples/example02.php

y el HTML que usa es https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/examples/res/example02.php